# Virtual reality MMO book with a cross genre chase

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds

About 15 years ago or so (so, no, not Halting State) I read a science fiction book about a virtual reality MMO.

The protagonist in the story was female.  There's a bit in there also where she was leading a new player orientation in game and referred to another woman who was, well, well endowed as having “great tracts of land”.  (Just a phrase that sticks in my mind.)

The core of the plot dealt with the title to some virtual estate that was won in a joust(?) and was being used for nefarious purposes prior to her claim to it.  The former owners were going to great measures (both in game and out of game) to reclaim the title.

One part of it involved a cross platform chase – her primary game was a fantasy dungeon crawl style... but in part of it they moved to other games on the system including a war reenactment game and a mecha game.

As I said, I remember reading this about 15 years ago (between 1995 and 2000) and it was likely newly published in that time frame (likely not from before '90).

Comment: Please tell me that you know [the origin of the "great tracts of land" meme](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001589/?ref_=tt_trv_qu). Please. If you don't I'm going to feel so *very* old.

Comment: @dmckee yep... its just one that stuck out in my mind while reading the that intro and I would hope would stick out in other people's minds when they are reading it to help me find the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be Dorothy Heydt's *[A Point of Honor](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?12535)* which was published in 1998. I don't remember the quote you do, but some other points match up. Here's the beginning of the description from Amazon:

> Sir Mary de Courey is the doughtiest knight in the virtual reality
> land of Chivalry. But when, in the real world, her plane crashes and
> her car is driven off the road, she finds herself in more trouble than
> single combat can solve. Someone appears to want to retrieve the
> mysterious manor that she won from an anonymous knight, and is willing
> to kill her to get it back.

Comment: That would indeed be it.